# PHP IPC with geth Ethereum

Tags: php, laravel, ipc, ethereum

I have setup geth Ether testnet. I want to communicate over IPC PHP with the client. Im on Ubuntu.
This is my current code:

```
$myValType = NULL;
$msg = "";
($key = ftok("/home/john/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc","="));
$queue = msg_get_queue($key);
msg_send($queue, 1, '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_start","params":[],"id":1}');
msg_receive($queue,0,$myValType,2048,$msg);
dd($msg); # (Die and Dump, Laravel)
```

This is the IPC File(FIFO?):

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 john john    0 Jun 17 01:30 geth.ipc=
```

This is working fine

```
echo '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"rpc_modules","params":[],"id":1}' | nc -U geth.ipc
```

I'm not sure how to actually communicate with the client. There is no response from it when sending. On `msg_receive` it just returns the initial sent message.

Someone hase expirience and be so kind and give me a proper solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: 
I found out how it works. I used [PHP Sockets](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/ref.sockets.php)

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_connect($sock, "/home/john/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc",1);
$myBuf = null;
$msg = "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"rpc_modules\",\"params\":[],\"id\":1}";
socket_send($sock, $msg, strlen($msg), MSG_EOF);
socket_recv ( $sock , $myBuf ,  100 ,MSG_WAITALL     );
```

Instead of using MSG Queues I could make it work with simple PHP Socket to the IPC File!

Answer (score 0):

if the result from ipc has dynamic size it is better to use the socket_read until the last character is "\n". then handle the result like this

```
public function ipcCall($data){
   $sock = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  socket_connect($sock, "/home/someuser/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc", 1);
  $msg = json_encode($data);
  socket_send($sock, $msg, strlen($msg), MSG_EOF);
  $result = '';
  while (($currentByte = socket_read($sock, 1)) != "\n") {
     $result .= $currentByte;
  }
 var_dump($result);
}
```